# grepl function - Combining a start and endstring

Tags: r

The last 2 hours ive been tyring to figure this out but i cant figure it out.

i got a variable where it starts with 4 letters ends with 2 numbers.

Now i want to subset only those starting with KJHB and ends with a number **between** 20-33.

The function im trying is:

```
df <- mydata
x <- seq(20,33)
df2 <- subset(df, grepl('^KJHB & x$, col1))
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is `mydata`?  Try with `grepl("^[A-Z]{4}.*[0-9]{2}$", col1)`

Comment: oh sorry `mydata`is just the dataframe i got with one of the column called `col1`. Are you suggesting the in the `[0-9]` i just write `[20-33]`?

Comment: No, you cannot write `[20-33]`

Comment: A regex for this might be "^KJHB.*(2[0-9])|(3[0123])$", though I don't know anything about r

Comment: I just tried it @Secespitus but with no luck :S

Comment: In your code example you are missing an apostrophe after your regex before the comma. Is this example copy-pasted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright i came up with a not totally correct answer but its working for me.

```
x <- paste("KJHB",seq(20,33), sep = "")
x <- as.data.frame(table(x))
df2 <- subset(df, col1 %in% x$x)
```

not the most correct way but did the job and the code is simple so a novice like me can understand it xD.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `stringr`.  This doesn't exactly check that it's the beginning or end of the string, but if it's a uniform pattern this may be useful:

```
my_match = function(string, start_string, num_seq){
   return( str_extract(string, start_string) && 
           any( !is.na( str_extract(string, as.character(num_seq)) ))
}

is_matched = my_match(df$your_col, "KJHB", 20:33)
df2 = df1[ is_matched, ]
```

There is probably something smarter that can be done with `str_locate` too.

Comment: World you be able to provide in `base R`as i am working on gov PC and they do not allow any package installation -.-